# Hashing n-grams by cyclic polynomials - java implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, string-matching, rabin-karp

I'm solving some problem that involves Rabin–Karp string search algorithm. This algorithm requires rolling hash to be faster then naive search. [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) describes how to implement rolling hash. I implemented "Rabin-Karp rolling hash" without problems and found few implementations [implementations](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/RabinKarp.java.html), but article also mentions computational complexity and that hashing n-grams by cyclic polynomials is prefered. It links to [BuzHash](https://www.se.auckland.ac.nz/courses/SOFTENG250/archive/2006/assignments/Hashing/BuzHash.java) implementation of such technique but I wonder how it can be used to build n-gram hash on top of it. I want to have something like [this](http://code.google.com/p/ngramhashing/) or

```
CPHash cp = new CPHash("efghijk");
cp.shiftRight('l') // now we got hash of "fghijki"
cp.shiftLeft('d') // "defghi"
```

for java.

For people who will encounter problems related with string search (like me) there are some articles that I found usefull: [1](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~simhaweb/cs151/lectures/module5/module5.html), [2](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/hash_function_technical_2.shtml), [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)

Comment: Are you sure, your examples are right? I don't think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently published an Apache licensed Java library which implements several rolling hash functions including Cyclic and Rabin-Karp:

http://code.google.com/p/rollinghashjava/

https://github.com/lemire/rollinghashjava